# MySQL Query is not working in 5.6

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT 
  p.ID, p.post_name as _slug, 
  p.post_title as _title, 
  p.post_modified as _updated, 
  m1.meta_value as _symbol,
  CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(m2.meta_value,'-',-1), INTEGER) as _rank 
FROM wp_posts AS p 
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m1 ON p.id = m1.post_id AND m1.meta_key = '_cc_symbol' 
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m2 ON p.id = m2.post_id AND m2.meta_key = '_cc_rank' 
where 
  p.post_type='cryptocurrency' ORDER by p.ID asc LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

This query is not working in MySQL Software version: 5.6.35-81.0

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INTEGER) as _rank, FROM wp_posts AS p LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m1
>   ON p.id = m1.post' at line 1

Thanks in advance

Comment: check your real code  ... seem you have a comma after the last  column and before the FROM word

Comment: But the error is coming before INTEGER keyword. Even i have corrected the comma still same error is coming

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, use `unsigned` or `signed` instead of `int`.  I prefer `cast()` to `convert()`:

```
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(m2.meta_value, '-', -1) as unsigned) as _rank
```

(In older versions of MySQL, `convert()` only converted between character sets, not types.)

Or, more simply, use silent conversion:

```
(SUBSTRING_INDEX(m2.meta_value, '-', -1) + 0) as _rank
```